# Does Zip uses a dictionary for compression? Is it possible to extract that dictionary and dump it to a text file?

Tags: header, zip

I would like to extract the dictionary of any compression algorithm (zip would be the one I would go for since it is widely used) and dump this dictionary to a text file.

I looked the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)) page to try and find the answer in the header, but I didn't really find an explicit answer to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zip can use multiple compression formats, one per compressed file.
For instance the Deflate and LZMA formats use a dictionary which is empty at the beginning and has a length of min(m,n) where m is the number of uncompressed bytes already processed and n is a preset value (32KB for Deflate).
So the dictionary is a portion of the uncompressed file on those formats.